# javascript JavaScript HTML Как каждую часть текста переместить в отдельный объект?

Tags: javascript, html, веб-программирование, объекты

Пишу свой текстовый редактор на contenteditable, и столкнулся с проблемой, мне нужно каждую часть текста переместить в отдельный объект, причем нужно учитывать тэги, как такое сделать?
Например вот такой текст набирает пользователь, и какой объект должен получиться:

```
Всем <b>привет</b>! Это мой <b>текстовый <i>редактор</i></b> <strike>зачеркнутый <b>текст)</b><strike> <font color=red>опасно!</font> и <u>страшно!</u> и <b><i><strike><u><font color="blue">фулл</font></u></strike></i></b>
```

```
{ 
  "text1": {
    "text": "Всем"
  },
  "text2": {
    "text": "привет",
    "bold": true
  },
  "text3": {
    "text": "! Это мой"
  },
  "text4": {
    "text": " текстовый",
    "bold": true
  },
  "text5": {
    "text": "редактор",
    "bold": true,
    "italic": true
  },
  "text6": {
    "text": "зачеркнутый",
    "strike": true
  },
  "text7": {
    "text": "текст)",
    "bold": true,
    "strike": true
  },
  "text8": {
    "text": "опасно!",
    "color": "red"
  },
  "text9": {
    "text": " и "
  },
  "text10": {
    "text": "страшно!",
    "underline": true
  },
  "text11": {
    "text": "фулл",
    "color": "blue",
    "bold": true,
    "italic": true,
    "underline": true,
    "strike": true
  }
}
```

Comment: Для чего ? Для сохранения в PDF или иной библиотеки ? В итоге нужен массив обьектов?

Comment: нет, в итоге мне нужен сам этот объект.

Comment: @Sergey, используемые теги как-то ограничиваются? например только `i`, `b` или могут быть любыми? Если могут быть любыми выставление свойств типа `bold`, `italic` может быть проблематичным

Comment: да, ограничиваются, i, b, u, strike и font(с параметром color)

Comment: @Sergey, Добавь в вопрос пример объекта с максимальным набором полей

Comment: добавил........

Answer (score -1):

это не решение вашей задачи, но этого более чем достаточно, чтобы вы смогли решить её сами - читай подогнать под себя

```
let div = document.createElement('div');
div.innerHTML = genTestData();
let _obj = foo(div.childNodes);
console.dir(_obj);
// ---
function foo(_nodeList, _obj = {}) {
    for (var k in _nodeList) {
        let node = _nodeList[k];
        let type = Object.prototype.toString.call(node);
        if ('[object Function]' === type || '[object Number]' === type)
            continue;
        // --
        // let isHTMLEl = '[object HTMLElement]' === type
        let nodeName = node.nodeName;
        let attributes = node.attributes;
        let childNodes = node.childNodes;
        let value = node.innerHTML || node.nodeValue;
        let self = _obj[`text${k}`] = { node, nodeName, value };
        if (attributes && attributes.length > 0)
            for (var k in attributes) {
                let attr = attributes[k];
                if ('[object Function]' === Object.prototype.toString.call(attr))
                    continue;
                self[attr['name']] = attr['value'];
            }
        if (childNodes && childNodes.length > 0)
            self['childNodes'] = foo(childNodes);
    }
    return _obj;
}
// ---
function genTestData() {
    return `
    Всем
    <b>
        привет
    </b>
    ! Это мой
    <b>
        текстовый
        <i>
            редактор
        </i>
    </b>
    <strike>
        зачеркнутый
        <b>
            текст)
        </b>
        <strike>
            <font color=red>
                опасно!
            </font>
            и
            <u>
                страшно!
            </u>
            и
            <b>
                <i>
                    <strike>
                        <u>
                            <font color="blue">
                                фулл
                            </font>
                        </u>
                    </strike>
                </i>
            </b>
        </strike>
    </strike>
    `
        // --> для удобства написания кода:
        // убрать пробелы
        .replace(/(  )/g, '')
        // убрать перенос строк
        .replace(/\n/g, '');
    // <==
}
```

Comment: наверное, лучше перебирать `nodeList` с помощью `forEach`